# $A$ is Positive Definite iff $B=\frac{1}{2}\left(A+A^{\mathrm{T}}\right)$ is positive definite

Tags: matrices, nonlinear-optimization, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

While studying Symmetric matrices for my nonlinear optimization class, I encountered the following problem:

**Problem:**

Suppose that $A$ is an arbitrary real square matrix. Show that $\mathbf{x}^{T} A \mathbf{x}>0$ for all $\mathbf{x} \neq \mathbf{0}$ if and only if the symmetric matrix $$B=\frac{1}{2}\left(A+A^{\mathrm{T}}\right)$$ is positive definite.

**Definitions/Observations:**

1. Suppose that $A$ is an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix. We say that $A$ is positive definite if $z^{T}Az > 0$ for all $z \in \mathbb{R}^{n}.$
2. For the other direction of the statement I was trying something very very similar, but it did not work either.
3. Related questions: [Prove that a square matrix $A$ is positive definite if and only if $A$+ $A^T$ is positive definite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1693828/prove-that-a-square-matrix-a-is-positive-definite-if-and-only-if-a-at-is)
   and
   [Is $A$ positive definite iff $\dfrac{A + A^H}{2}$ positive definite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2052894/is-a-positive-definite-iff-dfraca-ah2-positive-definite). One of them is a slightly different version, where the $\frac{1}{2}$ term does not appear. The other question regards the complex case, but for the sake of completeness I thought it should be nice to include!

**Attempt:**

I am trying to prove that if $B=\frac{1}{2}\left(A+A^{\mathrm{T}}\right)$ is positive definite, then $\mathbf{x}^{T} A \mathbf{x}>0$. What I did was basically rewriting $x^{T}Ax$ using the fact that $$2B - A^{T} = A$$ which leads us to:

$$x^{T}Ax = x^{T}\left(2B-A^{T}\right) x = \left(2 x^{T} B - x^{T} A^{T}\right) x$$

which equals:

$$2x^{T}Bx - x^{T}A^{T}x$$

Now, since $x^{T}A^{T} = \left(Ax\right)^{T}$, the above expression becomes:

$$2x^{T}Bx - \left(Ax\right)^{T}x$$

By using the symmetry of the inner product: $$\left(Ax\right)^{T}x = \langle Ax,x \rangle = \langle x, Ax \rangle = x^{T}Ax$$ one obtains:

$$
2x^{T}Bx - \left(Ax\right)^{T}x = 2x^{T}Bx - x^{T}Ax
$$

Now I am **stuck.**

I know that $x^{T}Bx > 0$, since we are assuming B is positive definite. However, I just cannot justify why the last (or any of the equalities) implies $x^{T}Ax > 0$.

Any help is appreciated, I am struggling really hard with this problem.

Thanks in advance, Lucas!

Comment: Do you see why $x^TBx\color{Red}{=} x^TAx$? Note the coefficient of $x_ix_j$ in $x^TAx$ is $(a_{ij}+a_{ji})$, after combining like terms, which means we'd get the same result if the matrix's $ij$ and $ji$ entries were both $\frac{1}{2}(a_{ij}+a_{ji})$. Indeed, this is the very first comment on the question you linked about $A+A^T$. Another way to show this is by transposing $x^TAx$ to get $x^TA^Tx$ is the same scalar, so averaging yields $x^TAx=\frac{1}{2}x^T(A+A^T)x$.

Comment: Very interesting! However, I did not understand the reasoning behind it... Also, what are the coefficients $x_{i} x_{j}$?

Comment: When you expand out $x^TAx$ explicitly it looks like the double sum $\sum_i \sum_j a_{ij}x_ix_j$, but you can combine $a_{ij}x_ix_j$ with $a_{ji}x_jx_i$ since they are like terms. | Also, you seem to think proving $A+A^T$ is pos def won't help you show $\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$ is pos def... do you realize any positive scalar multiple of a definite matrix is still a definite matrix? You can multiply/divide $x^TAx>0$ by any positive scalar.

Comment: At the time I just thought it was a typo, but you are right, the scalar multiple still works

Comment: So the goal is to show that $x^{T} B x=x^{T} A x$?

Comment: But how can the terms $a_{i j} x_{i} x_{j}$ and $a_{j i} x_{j} x_{i}$ be combined to yield the result?

Comment: Because $x_ix_j=x_jx_i$; multiplication is commutative! So $a_{ij}x_ix_j+a_{ji}x_jx_i=(a_{ij}+a_{ji})x_ix_j$. Try working out the $2\times2$ (or even $3\times3$) case for practice if it seems to abstract at the moment.

Comment: Nice! I see the algebra working now! However, I still dont get what is the strategy of the proof when using the explict double summation

Comment: I don't think of it as a "strategy of the proof" to write $x^TAx$ as a double summation. I consider that as simply wanting to see what $x^TAx$ looks like explicitly. If finding out what it looks like ends up helping in a proof, all the better.

Comment: Interesting! Would you be able to write the proof? I am very interested in your arguments! Usually, I only go about matrix problems by using matrix algebra

Comment: You can also think of this as regrouping the terms in the expression then adding it back to the original expression by pairing terms appropriately - meaning, seeing that $x^TAx=x^TA^Tx$ (since they have the same terms, only rearranged) and averaging to get $x^TAx=\frac{1}{2}x^T(A+A^T)x$. You may have seen a similar version of this trick, showing $1+2+\cdots+n$ equals $n+\cdots+2+1$ and averaging yields $1+2+\cdots+n=\frac{1}{2}(n+1)+\cdots+\frac{1}{2}(n+1)=n(n+1)/2$. The trick shows up quite a lot in many forms. | Basically all the ingredients for proofs are in the comments and answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x^TAx$ is a scalar, so it is equal to its transpose $x^TA^Tx$. This gives $x^TBx=x^TAx$ and you are done.

If $B$ is positive definite, from the equality you get $x^TAx>0\forall x\ne0$. Conversely if $x^TAx>0\forall x\ne0$, then $B$ is positive definite.

Comment: But why is $x^{T} B x=x^{T} A x$?

Comment: @Lucas Because $x^TBx=(x^TAx+x^TA^Tx)/2$.

Comment: What did you think of my work? Can it be reused somehow? I worked so hard on it, I am a bit sad to be honest that it was so far from the proof

Comment: Well, you are not so far after all. You got $x^TAx=2x^TBx-x^TAx$ which gives $x^TAx=x^TBx$ right? @Lucas

Comment: That is true! I just dont know how I did not see that! Thank you very very much!

Comment: Quick question: Since the definition says that $x^{T}Ax$ shoud be bigger than zero for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, is it a problem that we require $x$ different from zero in the proof? Because then it does not hold for every vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Comment: Do you think $x^TAx$ can be positive when $x=0$ for any matrix? The requirement $x\ne0$ is there is the definition as well. @Lucas

Comment: That is true, sorry for the confusion!